# Add values to a multi-multidimensional array with the same key

Tags: php, arrays

If I have:

```
<?php
$array1= array (
    "John"  => array("10" , "Holland"),
    "Cindy"  => array("20" , "Sweden"),
);


$array2= array (
    "John"  => ("Amsterdam"),
    "Cindy"  => ("Stockholm"),
);
?>
```

How can I add the values of **$array2** to the **$array1** (The same key) to get this **$array3**:

```
<?php
$array3= array (
    "John"  => array("10" , "Holland", "Amsterdam"),
    "Cindy"  => array("20" , "Sweden", "Stockholm"),
    );
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using function [array_merge_recursive()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge_recursive.asp)

```
  $array1= array (
        "John"  => array("10" , "Holland"),
        "Cindy"  => array("20" , "Sweden"),
    );


$array2= array (
    "John"  => ("Amsterdam"),
    "Cindy"  => ("Stockholm"),
);

echo '<pre>'; print_r(array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [John] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => Holland
            [2] => Amsterdam
        )

    [Cindy] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => Sweden
            [2] => Stockholm
        )

)
```